# Sharing oauth2 token with AJAX request to be sent to resource server

Tags: oauth2, ajax

I am a little confused on how the token is shared from the client to an AJAX script to the resource server in the oauth2 flow.

To explain the scenario I am trying to set up, I have

- a client (http://localhost:3000)
- a resource server (http://localhost:3001)
- an authentication server (http://localhost:3002)

The client is a server that is communicating with a user in the browser. The client obtains the token from the authentication server through the use of the authorization flow, it then sets the token as a cookie which is shared with the user. This means that the user has the token, but now the client wants the page delivered to the user to make an AJAX request to the resource server for information.

Since the token is locked between the client and the user, and CORS forbids the sharing of cookies when 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' is set. How can the AJAX request obtain the token and send it to the resource server to be validated?

Or am I confusing the workflow/trying something impossible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like you need a single-sign on/multiple domain solution.  I believe each domain will have it's own unique session token in that case, which means logging in and/or remembering a user for each as well.  (but why does the user have to interact with the resource server?  You could have the "client" server do that...)

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions possible.

**1. Allow CORS requests on authentication server**

The purpose of the authentication server is namely to provide tokens for *other* servers. That's why it is normal to allow CORS requests on the authentication server. Thus you can implement any additional logic in your application, including requests to the authentication server. Browser will not block them as CORS violation. If you want to make sure that the application code does not see the password in the plain form, you may want to use PKCE. See details in [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).

**2. Redirect, or implicit flow**

CORS requests on authentication server are not allowed. You send request to the resource server. It sees that authentication toke is missing or is expired. Then it *redirects* your request to the authentication server. The authentication server requests credentials and, if they are valid, *redirects* request to the resources server, and adds a valid token to the URL. The resource server validates token and returns you the requested resource.

**3. Cross-domain messaging**

In such case you don't need to allow CORS requests on authentication server. One should be careful: The code that sends the token from the authentication server to the resource server part should not use broadcast (because the token can be stolen by the script from malicious domain). Instead, one should send the token to the resource script window/frame only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! #1 makes sense, but (I think) it shouldn't be an issue as the client server in this case already has the token. My fear is that by making the token in the page accessible with JavaScript, it could be compromised via an XSS attack, but I am not sure how else to pass the token to the resource server as the token is locked between the client and the user's page, and if the origin is set to * it will not allow for credential passing. PKCE is a good idea, I will implement it once I have a good way of submitting the token from the page to the resource server.

Comment: @user134909: For the #2: When server receives a token in the URL, it can put it to a cookie. If you make this cookie *HttpOnly*, then no script, even your own, will be able to read this cookie.

Comment: That makes sense, so the resource server is the one that sets the token for the session not the client? Any idea why a lot of the explanations use diagrams that make it seem like the client application directly processes the token like the following https://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/oauth/auth_code_flow.png ? Is it because the auth server and the resource server are normally on the same machine?

Comment: @user134909: If redirection is used, then the client code has no chance to read the code from URL. This is an *implicit* flow. This flow is easier to implement. But it is vulnerable to attacks. That's why IETF [does not recommend to use it, see chapter 2.1.2.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-09). The diagram you refer does not use implicit flow. You can find more info about it at [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow).

Comment: Yes I didn't want to use the implicit flow, I am trying to figure out the authorization flow (I want to add in PKCE as well but I need to figure this out first). I used the Auth0 diagram initially and it was the source of confusion, as in the last step (9 and 10) it uses the token it got from the OAuth server and sends it to the resource server. So unless the resource server and the OAuth server are the same, this will fail because the Client (outside application) generated the cookie and sent it to the User (browser).

Comment: The diagrams are confusing because they assume that the client is a native application where the front end and back end are on the same machine. I am making the assumption that the "client" is really a web application on its own server, the "user" is a different device (a browser or a phone application), the oauth server is yet another server, and the resource server is another server (3 different servers, and 1 user's device in total). Is it possible that I am using the wrong architecture? Unless my AJAX requests make the request to the auth server it will always violate CORS.

Comment: The diagrams I referenced on Microsoft and on Auth0 web sites describe normal web applications running in browser. What diagrams with native applications do you mean?

Comment: Well in both diagrams the user is combined with the application itself, in the Microsoft one they even call it a native application. The weird part is that for a web app, there is a machine difference between the browser (User) and the web server (Client). Does that mean that the web server needs to act as a proxy to every web request to the resource server? (kinda like a middleman) Or is there some way of allowing the browser to access the token securely and create a new request with it to the resource server without involving the middleman (Client)?

Comment: In the Auth0 diagram it simply assumes that the server is the only recipient of the data (that is what I mean by they are combined in that sense).

Comment: The MS web site describes the common case. Where it is relevant, it describes additionally the specifics for native and mobile apps. Max be it is confusing that they in all examples use URL ".../nativeclient".

Comment: To Auth0: Why do you think they are combined? The authorization server is one thing and the server with application (they name it "Your API") is another thing.

Comment: Actually now that I look at it more you're right that wouldn't matter. I think I confused the limitations on sharing cookies in the browser, as it doesn't matter on the server as it can just grab the received token from the auth server and create a new connection with the resource server using it.

Comment: I guess maybe I am trying to do something that is not possible with the OAuth flow? Maybe the client web server has to act as a proxy for all requests to the resource server, and you cannot just make requests from the browser directly to the resource server? I can see how it would work for a local application but when there is the separation between the user and the "client server" it becomes a bit confusing on how the data should be sent (directly to the resource server from the browser or through the client server).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118353/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-user134909).